# What general structure does this type have?

Tags: haskell, types, higher-kinded-types

While hacking something up earlier, I created the following code:

```
newtype Callback a = Callback { unCallback :: a -> IO (Callback a) }

liftCallback :: (a -> IO ()) -> Callback a
liftCallback f = let cb = Callback $ \x -> (f x >> return cb) in cb

runCallback :: Callback a -> IO (a -> IO ())
runCallback cb =
    do ref <- newIORef cb
       return $ \x -> readIORef ref >>= ($ x) . unCallback >>= writeIORef ref
```

`Callback a` represents a function that handles some data and returns a new callback that should be used for the next notification. A callback which can basically replace itself, so to speak. `liftCallback` just lifts a normal function to my type, while `runCallback` uses an `IORef` to convert a `Callback` to a simple function.

The general structure of the type is:

```
data T m a = T (a -> m (T m a))
```

It looks much like this could be isomorphic to some well-known mathematical structure from category theory.

But what is it? Is it a monad or something? An applicative functor? A transformed monad? An arrow, even? Is there a search engine similar Hoogle that lets me search for general patterns like this?

Comment: I'd call it a "monadic costream," but that's somewhat idiosyncratic.

Comment: Monadic costream sounds good :-)

Comment: This reminds me of [`Free`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/free/3.3.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-Free.html) -- `Free f a = Either a (f (Either a (f (Either a (f ...` -- and [`Cofree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/free/3.3.1/doc/html/Control-Comonad-Cofree.html) -- `Cofree f a = (a, f (a, f (a, f ...` -- except with `(->)` instead of a sum/product. So `T f a = a -> f (a -> f (a -> f ...`, which makes it contravariant, unlike the other two.

Comment: (Since `(->)` isn't commutative, you could also get `newtype Bar f a = Bar { unBar :: f (Bar f a) -> a }`, which is a `Functor` whenever `f` is `Contravariant`, rather than the other way around.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The term you are looking for is [free monad transformer](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/free-monad-transformers.html).  The best place to learn how these work is to read the "Coroutine Pipelines" article in [issue 19 of The Monad Reader](http://themonadreader.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/issue19.pdf).  Mario Blazevic gives a very lucid description of how this type works, except he calls it the "Coroutine" type.

I wrote up his type in the `transformers-free` package and then it got merged into the `free` package, which is its new official home.

Your `Callback` type is isomorphic to:

```
type Callback a = forall r . FreeT ((->) a) IO r
```

To understand free monad transformers, you need to first [understand free monads](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html), which are just abstract syntax trees.  You give the free monad a functor which defines a single step in the syntax tree, and then it creates a `Monad` from that `Functor` that is basically a list of those types of steps.  So if you had:

```
Free ((->) a) r
```

That would be a syntax tree that accepts zero or more `a`s as input and then returns a value `r`.

However, usually we want to embed effects or make the next step of the syntax tree dependent on some effect.  To do that, we simply promote our free monad to a free monad transformer, which interleaves the base monad between syntax tree steps.  In the case of your `Callback` type, you are interleaving `IO` in between each input step, so your base monad is `IO`:

```
FreeT ((->) a) IO r
```

The nice thing about free monads is that they are automatically monads for any functor, so we can take advantage of this to use `do` notation to assemble our syntax tree.  For example, I can define an `await` command that will bind the input within the monad:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Free

await :: (Monad m) => FreeT ((->) a) m a
await = liftF id
```

Now I have a DSL for writing `Callback`s:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Free

printer :: (Show a) => FreeT ((->) a) IO r
printer = forever $ do
    a <- await
    lift $ print a
```

Notice that I never had to define the necessary `Monad` instance.  Both `FreeT f` and `Free f` are automatically `Monad`s for any functor `f`, and in this case `((->) a)` is our functor, so it automatically does the right thing.  That's the magic of category theory!

Also, we never had to define a `MonadTrans` instance in order to use `lift`.  `FreeT f` is automatically a monad transformer, given any functor `f`, so it took care of that for us, too.

Our printer is a suitable `Callback`, so we can feed it values just by deconstructing the free monad transformer:

```
feed :: [a] -> FreeT ((->) a) IO r -> IO ()
feed as callback = do
    x <- runFreeT callback
    case x of
        Pure _ -> return ()
        Free k -> case as of
            []   -> return ()
            b:bs -> feed bs (k b)
```

The actual printing occurs when we bind `runFreeT callback`, which then gives us the next step in the syntax tree, which we feed the next element of the list.

Let's try it:

```
>>> feed [1..5] printer
1
2
3
4
5
```

However, you don't even need to write all this up yourself.  As Petr pointed out, my `pipes` library abstracts common streaming patterns like this for you.  Your callback is just:

```
forall r . Consumer a IO r
```

The way we'd define `printer` using `pipes` is:

```
printer = forever $ do
    a <- await
    lift $ print a
```

... and we can feed it a list of values like so:

```
>>> runEffect $ each [1..5] >-> printer
1
2
3
4
5
```

I designed `pipes` to encompass a very large range of streaming abstractions like these in such a way that you can always use `do` notation to build each streaming component.  `pipes` also comes with a wide variety of elegant solutions for things like state and error handling, and bidirectional flow of information, so if you formulate your `Callback` abstraction in terms of `pipes`, you tap into a ton of useful machinery for free.

If you want to learn more about `pipes`, I recommend you [read the tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/4.1.0/doc/html/Pipes-Tutorial.html).

Comment: Wow, that is a superb answer! Thanks a lot, it will probably take me a while to comprehend this all.

Answer (score 8):

The general structure of the type looks to me like

```
data T (~>) a = T (a ~> T (~>) a)
```

where `(~>) = Kleisli m` in your terms (an arrow).

---

`Callback` itself doesn't look like an instance of any standard Haskell typeclass I can think of, but it is a Contravariant Functor (also known as Cofunctor, misleadingly as it turns out). As it is not included in any of the libraries that come with GHC, there exist several definitions of it on Hackage ([use this one](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/contravariant/0.3/doc/html/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html)), but they all look something like this:

```
class Contravariant f where
    contramap :: (b -> a) -> f a -> f b
 -- c.f. fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Then

```
instance Contravariant Callback where
    contramap f (Callback k) = Callback ((fmap . liftM . contramap) f (f . k))
```

Is there some more exotic structure from category theory that `Callback` possesses? I don't know.

Comment: The right place to get `Cofunctor` is from the contravariant package. And the right thing to do is to not call it cofunctor, since the co could also stand for "covariant". http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/contravariant/0.3/doc/html/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html

Comment: I've learnt a couple of things today then, good. I shall edit the names in my answer. If any other non---category theorists are wondering what a “covariant functor” might be: [it's just an ordinary functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Covariance_and_contravariance).

Comment: @sclv I think the better reason to not call it "cofunctor" is that the dual notion of functor is also functor... I think...

Comment: they're both good reasons, and together they're an even better reason.

Answer (score 6):

I think that this type is very close to what I have heard called a 'Circuit', which is a type of arrow. Ignoring for a moment the IO part (as we can have this just by transforming a Kliesli arrow) the circuit transformer is:

```
newtype CircuitT a b c = CircuitT { unCircuitT :: a b (c, CircuitT a b c) }
```

This is basicall an arrow that returns a new arrow to use for the next input each time. All of the common arrow classes (including loop) can be implemented for this arrow transformer as long as the base arrow supports them. Now, all we have to do to make it notionally the same as the type you mention is to get rid of that extra output. This is easily done, and so we find:

```
Callback a ~=~ CircuitT (Kleisli IO) a ()
```

As if we look at the right hand side:

```
CircuitT (Kleisli IO) a () ~=~
  (Kliesli IO) a ((), CircuitT (Kleisli IO) a ()) ~=~
  a -> IO ((), CircuitT (Kliesli IO) a ())
```

And from here, you can see how this is similar to Callback a, except we also output a unit value. As the unit value is in a tuple with something else anyway, this really doesn't tell us much, so I would say they're basically the same.

N.B. I used ~=~ for similar but not entirely equivalent to, for some reason. They are very closely similar though, in particular note that we could convert a `Callback a` into a `CircuitT (Kleisli IO) a ()` and vice-versa.

EDIT: I would also fully agree with the ideas that this is A) a monadic costream (monadic operation expecitng an infinite number of values, I think this means) and B) a consume-only pipe (which is in many ways very similar to the circuit type with no output, or rather output set to (), as such a pipe could also have had output).

Comment: I think they are "exactly the same" (or they would be if `(a,()) = a` were true (tuples are not true products, but most of the time it is okay to pretend they are).

Comment: Well, this was my feeling too, if it truly was the case that the only value of type () was () then they would be exactly the same, but of course undefined is also of type ().

Comment: I like this answer very much. As it happens, I came across the `Circuit` type in a tutorial about arrows just days ago, but had already forgotten about it already. I think the similarity to sinks/consumers is the most important one, because now that I think of it, what I use this thing for is actually processing a stream of `a`s :)

Answer (score 3):

Just an observation, your type seems quite related to [`Consumer p a m`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/3.1.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Synonym.html#t%3aConsumer) appearing in the [pipes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-3.1.0) library (and probably other similar librarties as well):

```
type Consumer p a = p () a () C
-- A Pipe that consumes values
-- Consumers never respond.
```

where `C` is an empty data type and `p` is an instance of [`Proxy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/3.1.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Class.html#t%3aProxy) type class. It consumes values of type `a` and never produces any (because its output type is empty).

For example, we could convert a `Callback` into a `Consumer`:

```
import Control.Proxy
import Control.Proxy.Synonym

newtype Callback m a = Callback { unCallback :: a -> m (Callback m a) }

-- No values produced, hence the polymorphic return type `r`.
-- We could replace `r` with `C` as well.
consumer :: (Proxy p, Monad m) => Callback m a -> () -> Consumer p a m r
consumer c () = runIdentityP (run c)
  where
    run (Callback c) = request () >>= lift . c >>= run
```

See [the tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/3.1.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Tutorial.html).

(This should have been rather a comment, but it's a bit too long.)

Comment: Yeah, thinking about it, this makes perfect sense. I'm basically using this to process a stream of `a`s